# Moving shapes in JavaFX canvas

Tags: animation, canvas, javafx

I would like to know if it's possible to use the GraphicsContext of a Canvas to create a circle(or any shape created with GraphicsContext) and then move it around on the canvas. If it is, what's the algorithm for doing so? I'm used to working with Java and I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow.  What have you attempted so far? - if you show some code you are much more likely to get a positive response.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically, the way this works is that you setup a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) and update the location of the shape based on some [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).  Then, in an [AnimationTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) you paint your canvas.

[image: circlefun]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatedCircleOnCanvas extends Application {
    public static final double W = 200; // canvas dimensions.
    public static final double H = 200;

    public static final double D = 20;  // diameter.

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        DoubleProperty x  = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty y  = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
                    new KeyValue(x, 0),
                    new KeyValue(y, 0)
            ),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),
                    new KeyValue(x, W - D),
                    new KeyValue(y, H - D)
            )
        );
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(W, H);
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
                gc.setFill(Color.CORNSILK);
                gc.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
                gc.setFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
                gc.fillOval(
                    x.doubleValue(),
                    y.doubleValue(),
                    D,
                    D
                );
            }
        };

        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(
                new Group(
                    canvas
                )
            )
        );
        stage.show();

        timer.start();
        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

It is however simpler to not use a Canvas, but instead use a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) containing a [Circle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html) in combination with a [TranslateTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html).

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you very much, I've spent a lot of hours googling this and couldn't find anything.
You are also correct about the Pane and Circle solution being simpler, the idea was to do this in Java and then I thought it would be pretty much the same to use JavaFX (not one of my smartest thoughts)
Thanks again!

Comment: I was animating shape nodes on a Pane that was itself inside of a pane, but I could not understand how the coordinate system worked relative to the parent Panes. I am now attempting to draw shapes on Canvas for animation. As I need many shapes, it would seem that Canvas is a better fit for performance.

Comment: @burntsuger, this is somewhat unrelated to the original question, but you may be interested in [JavaFX performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506637/javafx-2-drawing-performance) and some [Tips and Tricks](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Performance+Tips+and+Tricks).  Oracle [benchmarked JavaFX performance](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2013/connect/fileDownload/session/C3B800733D28DB105AB5FC964843D1AB/CON1905_Heidrich.pptx) and canvas can be slower than nodes (pages 41-52).  Performance with each is app specific, so you might want to benchmark your app on both.